# ExpandableListViewの中にExpandableListViewを入れる方法

Tags: android, kotlin

①ExpandableListView(id:test1)
②ExpandableListView(id:test2)

②が表示されません。
①と②を同じxmlファイルに記載すると問題なく表示されます。

①の中に②を入れると、

> val test1 = requireView().findViewById(R.id.test1)

→問題なく取得可能

> val test2 = requireView().findViewById(R.id.test2)

→デバッグモードで見るとViewがnullになっていて取得不可能

Answer (score 1):

自己解決。
処理を記載するファイル(.kt）を間違えていました。